# Join a number of lines with a starting and ending pattern

Tags: shell-script, sed

I've a file like this:

```
method AAA one (1,111):
   some_text_1
method BBB two (2,
   222):
   tuesday
method CCC three (3,
    333):
   sunny_day
method DDD four (4,
    444_a,
    444_b):
   last_week
```

I want it to look like this:

```
method AAA one (1,111):
   some_text_1
method BBB two (2,222):
   tuesday
method CCC three (3,333):
   sunny_day
method DDD four (4,444_a,444_b):
   last_week
```

I've this sed command that nearly does it:

```
sed -i '/method/,/):/ p; :a; N; $!b a; s/\n\s\{1,\}//g' file.txt
```

It gives this output:

```
method AAA one (1,111):
method AAA one (1,111):some_text_1
method BBB two (2,222):tuesday
method CCC three (3,333):sunny_day
method DDD four (4,444_a,444_b): last_week
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one), **39. Append a line to the next if it ends with a backslash "\"**, but changing the backslash to comma and extending the substitution to include following whitespace:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/,$/N; s/,\n[[:blank:]]*/,/; ta' file
method AAA one (1,111):
   some_text_1
method BBB two (2,222):
   tuesday
method CCC three (3,333):
   sunny_day
method DDD four (4,444_a,444_b):
   last_week
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```bsh
awk 'f{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "")} {f=/,$/; ORS = f ? "" : RS} 1'
```

This will set a flag `f` whenever a line ends with `,`. Based on the flag, output record separator will be empty string or same as input record separator (which is newline by default). Whenever the flag is set, the next line's starting whitespace characters will also be deleted.

With `perl`, assuming the input is small enough to be processed as a single string:

```bsh
perl -0777 -pe 's/,\n\s*/,/g'
```

The above solutions will fail if you have lines ending with `,` that are not part of the `method` function. In such cases, assuming there will be only one pair of `()` characters for the `method` portion, you can use:

```bsh
perl -0777 -pe 's/method[^(]+\([^)]+\)/$&=~s|\n\s*||gr/ge'
```

Here `method[^(]+\([^)]+\)` will match from `method` to first `(` and `)` characters. The replacement section has another Perl code which will act on the matched portion to remove newlines followed by optional whitespace characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using `gawk`:

```
awk 'function del_space(){gsub(/^\s+/,""); };
/,$/ {if (NR==l) del_space(); a=a $0; l=NR+1; next}
NR==l{del_space(); $0=a $0; a=""}1' file
```

As long as a comma is found at the end of line, variable `a` saves current input record(`$0`) followed by a space, then followed by previous record. `next` prevents further actions on this record, i.e. there won't be printing when `awk`'s `1` idiom for printing is used at the end of command.

In next record after pattern is matched `$0=a $0;a="";` sets current input record(`$0`) to `a` followed by old `$0` and variable `a` to `""` respectively.

The `del_space()` function replaces space from start of next record after `,` is found at the end of record.

If you want a space after comma, then this should be changed to this:

```
awk 'function del_space(){gsub(/^\s+/,""); };
/,$/ {if (NR==l) del_space(); a=a $0; l=NR+1; next}
NR==l{del_space(); $0=a FS $0; a=""}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

We setup a `do-while` loop with multiple breakout conditions, as shown.

- line has no method string in it , breakout.
- line is fully formed , has method and also ): in it, breakout
- last line, quit
- for every other line, join it with next and strip the joining whitespace(s).

```
sed -e '
  :loop
    /method/!b
    /method.*):/b
    $q
    N;s/\n\s*//
  b loop
' file.txt
```

---

Output:

```
method AAA one (1,111):
   some_text_1
method BBB two (2,222):
   tuesday
method CCC three (3,333):
   sunny_day
method DDD four (4,444_a,444_b):
   last_week
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `sed`'er (POSIX):

```
sed ':a;/^method/!b;/[^:]$/N;s/[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*/ /g;ta'
```

- DEF label `:a`
- IF pattern space does not start with `method`

  - THEN skip to end by `b`
- ELSE if it does not end with `:`

  - THEN append next line using `N`.
- SUBSTITUTE `spaces`* + `\n` + `spaces`* with `' '`

  - IF there was a substitution, go back to `:a`
- END print

---

Should handle cases like:

```
method XXX foo (8,
    888):
   bar,
   baz

method
HHH
bar
(
aa,
bb):
    lor
```

Does give some extra spaces around parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Another `Posix sed` way :

```
sed '
  /,$/bl
  be
  :l
    N
    s/\n *//g
    /):$/!bl
  :e
' data
```

- When find a comma terminated string jump to `l` label : `/,$/bl`

  - Otherwise jump to `e` (An empty label, here just for print): `be`
- the `l` label emulates a loop as follow:

  - Get the next line : `N`
  - Replace the new line and the leading spaces on this: `s/\n *//g`
  - If the current lines **DONT** endings with a `):` then repeat the loop and grab another line again (and repeat all): `/):$/!bl`
  - Else enter in the `e` label and print the line.